# Trying to Delete a value out of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to delete ("0.00") out of a cell in column P. The row I've highlighted is not working?

```
Sub Delete a Cell value

Dim rngToCheck As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set rngToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("P13:P61")

For Each rng In rngToCheck
*If Cells = ("0.00") Then*
rng.Cells = Delete
End If

Next rng

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: ```rng.cells = delete``` is also problematic.

Comment: Are you trying to delete the cell and shift other cells? or delete that text inside the cell? or delete the rows? just clear the cell contents? does the match have to be of the whole cell, or just a part?

Comment: Trying to delete the text inside the cell. To Match the whole cell

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the `rng` object when you suddenly changed to refer to `Cells`. Also there is one `End If` too much. Check for the actual value instead of the formatted display. Assign `Value` to empty `("")` to clear content.

```
Sub DeleteACellValue()

    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("B7:B9")
    For Each cell In rngToCheck
        If cell.Text = "0.00" Then
            cell.Text = ""
        End If
    Next cell

'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code below needs to have 0 as 0.00 because that`s the way it`s formatted see below. Soon as i try to use 0.00 it fails.

Comment: Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("P13:P61")
    For Each cell In rngToCheck
        If cell.Value = "0.00" Then
            cell.Value = Clear
        End If
    Next cell


End If
End Sub

Comment: @user It would have been good for you to say how "it fails". Anyway, I changed it to check for the text instead of the value. OK?

Comment: Thanks that`s worked a treat. Except i need all the formatting to stay as it was?

Comment: @user So, what formatting do you have there and how did it change? Did you assign `cell.Text = ""` as I showed you or did you do `cell.Clear`?

Comment: I did what you said but it took away the borders and number formatting

Comment: @user Assigning `cell.Text = "" ` can not affect cell borders, cell color, nor number formatting. Please double check once more. In a previous comment you show `then cell.Value = Clear` which is not what I have been telling you. Do as I told you: `cell.Text = ""`.

Comment: @user Btw, Looking at your history, I recommend that you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I did what you said but it now has shown up an error which goes yellow over code (cell.Text = "")  then error says (cell.Text="0.00").

Comment: Please take a snip of the area and post the image as an edit within your original question, thank you. Also try to fit in the same snip the code as you have it now.

Comment: Is this still an open question?

Answer (score 0):

This vba code worked on my end. Be sure to use the .clear function instead of .delete

Let me know if this solves your question or if there is something else I can help with.
Thanks!

```
Sub ClearCell()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Integer, counter As Integer

'RANGE TO EVALUATE
  Set rng = Range("P13:P61")

'initialize i to 1
  i = 1

 'Loop for a count of 1 to number of rows
   For counter = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

 'if cell i in the range contains value, delete cell, else increment i
   If rng.Cells(i) = "0" Then
       rng.Cells(i).Clear
   Else
       i = i + 1
  End If
  Next
End Sub
```